# js button spinner not working on wordpress website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have written a html-css-js code for an animated button spinner which works fine in any other console after clicking (as you can see in the recording), but the js part is not working on the wordpress page. Does anybody happen to know the solution? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Screen recording of the issue:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFiKFy06a1P85Uh0HhJsB-RV9NoJbF8V/view?usp=share_link

console.log message shows in inspector, so the js code should be working!
I even tested it on another websites while all plugins were deactivated.

### Source code:

```js
const theButton = document.querySelector(".button-motion");
theButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  theButton.classList.add("button--loading");
});
```

```css
.button-motion {
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: #ffffff !important;
    border: 1;
    outline: none;
    border-width: thin !important;
    border-color: #ddc8a8 !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button-motion:hover {
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button-motion:active {
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button__text {
    font: 13px "arial", sans;
    color: #ad7d4e;
    transition: all 0s;
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button--loading .button__text {
    background: #ffffff !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.button--loading::after {
    content: "";
    background: #ffffff !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1.5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ad7d4e;
    border-radius: 70%;
    animation: button-loading-spinner 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center>
    <button type="button" class="button-motion">
      <span class="button__text">Boka</span>
    </button>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML:
<body>
<center>
<button type="button" class="button-motion">
<span class="button__text">Boka</span>
</button>
</center>
</body>

Comment: CSS (part1): 
.button-motion {
width: 80px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
padding: 5px 20px;
background: #ffffff !important;
border: 1;
outline: none;
border-width: thin !important;
border-color: #DDC8A8 !important;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.button-motion:hover {
background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button-motion:active {
background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button__text {
font: 13px "arial", sans;
color: #AD7D4E;
transition: all 0.0s;
background: #ffffff !important;
}
.button--loading .button__text {

Comment: CSS (part2):
background: #ffffff !important;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
}
.button--loading::after {
content: "";
background: #ffffff !important;
position: absolute;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
border: 1.5px solid transparent;
border-top-color: #AD7D4E;
border-radius: 70%;
animation: button-loading-spinner 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

Comment: JS:
const theButton = document.querySelector(".button-motion");
theButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
theButton.classList.add("button--loading");
});

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kindly check that in WP the JS file is being applied on the button (if it is linked to the HTML file for example)